# Java Basics: create class object

Tags: java, c++

In C++:

```
class Rectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area () {return (x*y);}
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  rect.set_values (3,4);
}
```

In Java:

```
class Rectangle {
    int x, y;
    void set_values (int x,int y);
    int area () {return (x*y);}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(3,4);

}
```

In C++ compiler will create `rect` object & reserve memory 4 bytes. I want to know How Java is creating object?

Comment: Of course your Java snippet isn't legal syntax :).  But a Java "new Rectangle (I, J)" basically does the same thing as C++ "new Rectangle (I, J)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do: -

```
Rectangle rect;
```

in **C++**, it invokes, the 0-arg default constructor, provided by the compiler.

If you wanted to use a 2-arg constructor, you would have to do: -

```
Rectangle rect(3, 4);
```

wherein, you would have to provide a 2-arg constructor explicitly, else it won't compile.

---

Now, similar is the case in Java. If you do: -

```
new Rectangle();
```

then its ok, because, in that case, compiler will provide you with a default 0-arg constructor, as in C++, but when your create object like: -

```
new Rectangle(3, 4);
```

Then you would have to explicitly provide the class with a 2-arg constructor, else it won't compile, as in your 2nd example, that won't compile.

Also, once you provide a `parameterized constructor`, then in that case, Compiler won't provide the default constructor. You would have to provide a 0-arg constructor explicitly, if you want to use one. This suffice in both, `Java` and `C++`

Now, as per the `memory allocation` is concerned, since Java is platform independent, so the size of `int` type is `32 bits`, in all platforms. This is in contrast to `C++` where size of data types are platform dependent.

See [**`JVM Specification - The Structure of JVM`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html) for detaled information about the allocation of various types.

**P.S.**: -

I suggest you to go through the below link, for basics of Java classes and objects: -

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Plus, once you provide a constructor with arguments, you need to explicitly provide a default (no-arg) constructor if you want your class to have one.

Answer (score 0):

`32` or `64` bits for:

```
Rectangle rect
```

is reserved on the Stack.

Then, `32 + 32 = 64 bits` is allocated from the Heap for:

```
new Rectangle(3,4);
```

Java is a platform independent language and all primitive types have specific sizes.

Please see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

In java `rect` is not an object, but actually a `reference` to point the `object`.

When you say `new Rectangle(3,4);` it will create an `object` inside the `heap` and return the `reference address` of that `object`, and reference address is `assigned` to a variable of the appropriate type, which is `Rectangle` `rect` in your case.

[image]

resource [creating object in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)